# Error importing reducers from index file

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm exporting a users reducer like this:

```
export default function users
```

and exporting from an index.js file like this:

```
export users from './users'
```

to be able to do

```
import * as reducers from './redux'
```

but I get this error

```
    Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected { (1:7)

> 1 | export users from './users'
    |        ^
  2 |
```

Comment: Please paste a proper code here.This is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you may need to try `export {default as users} from "./users"`.

The main reference info for ES6 modules is Dr. Axel Rauschmayer's book "Exploring ES6", and specifically the [section on module import export syntax](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_importing-exporting-details).